Keep getting error while uploading Django project in vercel
While I am deploying my Django project using Vercel I am keep getting this error
Error: No Output Directory named "staticfiles_build" found after the Build completed. You can configure the Output Directory in your Project Settings

I tried many things to resolve the error, but nothing is working.
This is my setting.py code
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles_build', 'static')

i wanted to deploy my project online with the help of Vercel but I am keep getting the error

See https://dev.to/doridoro/deploy-a-django-app-with-postgresql-database-on-vercel-1965

Here are my configs, that works for me:
// settings.py
STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles" / "static"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]

// vercel_build.sh
echo "Building project packages..."
echo "Installing project requirements..."
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

echo "Installing tailwindcss and dependencies..."
python3 manage.py tailwind install

echo "Building tailwindcss..."
python3 manage.py tailwind build

echo "Migrating Database..."
python3 manage.py makemigrations --noinput
python3 manage.py migrate --noinput

echo "Collecting static files..."
python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput

// vercel.json
{
  "regions": ["sin1"],
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "configs/wsgi.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python",
      "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "python3.9" }
    },
    {
      "src": "vercel_build.sh",
      "use": "@vercel/static-build",
      "config": {
        "distDir": "staticfiles"
      }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/static/(.*)",
      "dest": "/static/$1"
    },
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "configs/wsgi.py"
    }
  ]
}

